# Increase number of digits on presented ORs and 95% CI by tbl_regression in gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

How can I increase the number of digits on the exponentiated ORs and it corresponding 95% CI from the default 2 to say 3 digits?

```
library(gtsummary)
data(trial)
  glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
```

```
res <- glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) %>%
          tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>% style_sigfig( digits = 3)
#Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `expoentiate` is `FALSE`, we can modify the `style_sigfig` and if it is `TRUE`, change the `digits` in `style_ratio` as mentioned in the `?tbl_regression

> estimate_fun - Function to round and format coefficient estimates. Default is style_sigfig when the coefficients are not transformed, and style_ratio when the coefficients have been exponentiated.

By default, both of them are 2.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
glm(response ~ trt, trial, family = binomial) %>%
      tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, 
        estimate_fun = purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 3),
         pvalue_fun = purrr::partial(style_sigfig, digits = 3))
```

[image]

Comment: I had taken note of that, and when I tried it, I got an error below:  Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: @Nelly I updated the post from the earlier version

Comment: @Nelly : When you get errors you should post the entire text of the error message in the body of your question (not in comments) as well as the text of any other warnings that appear on your console.